# react-native redux action not being called

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-persist

**PROBLEM**

The actions isn't being called from my component.

**Stuff im using:**

```
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.13.1",
"react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
"redux": "^4.0.5",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.63.3",
```

**My setup**

I am using a package `"react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0"` , it has a prop which i can pass down a callback function to handle onSelects.

```
<CountryPicker
  {...{
  countryCode: country,
  onSelect: (country) => this.onSelectCN(country),
  }}
/>
...
...
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => (bindActionCreators({
  setUserCountry,
}, dispatch));

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  country: state.country
});

const Community = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CommunityComponent);

export { Community };
```

**This is the onSelect Method:**

```
onSelectCN = (country) => {
    console.log(country)
    setUserCountry()
  }
```

**This is the redux actions it SHOULD call but isn't:**

```
//persisted
export const setUserCountry = () => (storeDispatch: Dispatch<any>) => {
  console.log('inside actions,dispatching aft this msg')
  return storeDispatch({
      type: SET_USER_COUNTRY,
      payload:'SG'
  })
};
```

But it's not calling as it does not display the console log.

**This is the reducer**

```
function countrySettings(state = {
  country: '',
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USER_COUNTRY:
      return {...state, country: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**This is my store configuration:**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index'


// Middleware: Redux Persist Config
const persistConfig = {
  // Root
  key: 'root',
  // Storage Method (React Native)
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  // Whitelist (Save Specific Reducers)
  whitelist: [
    'countrySettings',
  ],
  // Blacklist (Don't Save Specific Reducers)
  blacklist: [
   .......
  ],
};
// Middleware: Redux Persist Persisted Reducer
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
// Redux: Store
const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  applyMiddleware(
    thunkMiddleware,
  ),
);
// Middleware: Redux Persist Persister
let persistor = persistStore(store);
// Exports
export {
  store,
  persistor,
};
```

**And this is my App.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Router from './src/Router';
import reducer from './src/reducers';
import theme from './src/styles/DefaultTheme';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

import { store, persistor } from './src/configureStore';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <Router />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: where do u import or pull `setUserCountry` before calling it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onSelectCN = (country) => {
  console.log(country)
  this.props.setUserCountry()
}
```

Not sure why you pass country to the function and then not use it for the action creator function.